# Twincat 3 Eventlogger c# reference

Tags: c#, twincat, twincat-ads-.net

In the [webinar](http://multimedia.beckhoff.com/webinar/en/webinar-twincat-3-eventlogger/default.htm) there is an example written in c# on how to access events from the eventlogger (14 minutes in). In the example there is a type, TcEventlogger, however I'm not able to find the dll that contains this type. I have the latest version (3.1.4022.22) installed on my computer. Anyone know where to find the referred library?

[image: Code example in webinar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the dll myself. It was:

C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Components\TcEventLoggerV2\TcEventLoggerAdsProxy.dll or rather
{Install Path}\TwinCAT\3.1\Components\TcEventLoggerV2\TcEventLoggerAdsProxy.dll